# Multiple criteria in Elasticsearch request

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch, wildcard

I am using the below POST request in my Ajax call however I am not able to add additional search criteria. I also want to be able to search on a number of other fields specifically with wildcards.  Example firstName of "j*" and lastName of "p*".   How would I add two more criteria to this type of query.  I know how to do it in a curl request when it was a GET request but not sure how to do it as a POST request.

On the GET requests I would just add the following.

```
+%2bfirstName:j*
```

POST Request

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "range": {
                    "date": {
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": false,
                        "from": "1999-01-01",
                        "to": "2002-01-01"
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "locationNumber": "453"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine several criteria in your query using [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html). For example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "date": {
                                    "include_lower": true,
                                    "include_upper": false,
                                    "from": "1999-01-01",
                                    "to": "2002-01-01"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "firstName": "j*"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "locationNumber": "453"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I found I can also keep adding wildcards for the other fields. This is pretty awesome. Do you have any tips for generating these calls with JS?